# The Boolean-valued model $V^B$ is full.

Tags: set-theory, boolean-algebra

I was reading this lemma from Jech's tome and came across a "clearly, ..." so i tried to prove it on my own but i'm failing miserably. To give context:

> **Lemma 14.19.** $V^B$ *is full*. *Given a formula* $\varphi(x, ...)$, *there exists some* $a \in V^B$ *such that*, $$ \|\varphi(a, ...)\| = \|\exists x\varphi(x, ...)\|$$ *Proof.* $\le$ holds for every $a$ because of the definition of $\|\exists x\varphi(x, ...)\|$, we wish to find $a \in V^B$ such that $\ge$ holds. Let $u_0 = \|\exists x\varphi(x, ...)\|$. Let $$ D = \{u \in B: \text{there is some } a_u \text{ such that } u \le \|\varphi(a_u, ...)\|\}.$$
>   It is clear that $D$ is open and dense below $u_0$. Let W be a maximal set of pairwise disjoint elements of $D$; clearly, $\sum\{u: u\in W\} \ge u_0$. By lemma 14.18 we are done.$\hspace{3cm}\Box$

---

Now if $u \in D$ we know that there exists some $a_u$ such that $u \le \|\varphi(a_u, ...)\|$, so $u \le \sum_{a \in V^B}\|\varphi(a, ...)\| = \|\exists x\varphi(x, ...)\| = u_0$ and again for each $u \in W$ we have $u \le u_0$ and in order to prove $\sum\{u: u\in W\} \ge u_0$ we have to prove $\sum\{u: u\in W\} = u_0$. And this is where i'm stuck. I have tried reaching a contradiction by assuming that equality doesn't hold but i got no results. Any hints or answers are appreciated.
Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Just recall the definition of the value of the existential formula. $\bigvee D=\|\exists x\varphi(x, ...)\|$ by definition. In particular $\|\varphi(a, ...)\|\in D$ for every $a$.

Comment: @Apostolos, I know but what i am struggling is linking it to $\sum W$.

Comment: $\sum W=\sum D$ since it's maximal, no?

Comment: How does the maximality of $W$ imply that?

Comment: Assume $\sum W<\sum D$ hence there is a $u\in D$ such that $(\sum W)+u>\sum W$. Then $u-\sum W\leq u$ so $u-\sum W\in D$ and thus $W\cup\{u-\sum W\}$ is a set of pairwise disjoint elements of $D$ extending $W$ contradicting the maximality of $W$.

Comment: By $u - \sum W$ you mean $u . -\sum W$, right?

Comment: I mean the $u\cdot(-\sum W)$, yes.