# Why $V^B$ satisfies Separation

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, forcing

In Chapter 14 of Jech's *Set Theory*, he writes the following (for the definition of $V^B$ see [my question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4493601/understanding-why-vb-is-full)):

> **Theorem 14.24.** Every axiom of ZFC is valid in $V^B.$

For the proof of Separation, he writes the following:

> Let $\varphi$ be a formula. We prove that for every $X\in V^B$ there is a $Y\in V^B$ such that
> $$(14.22) \qquad ||Y\subseteq X||=1 \text{ and } ||(\forall z\in X)(\varphi(z)\leftrightarrow z\in Y)||=1.$$
> Let $Y\in V^B$ be as follows:
> $$\text{dom}(Y)=\text{dom}(X),\quad Y(t)=X(t)\cdot ||\varphi(t)||.$$
> For every $x\in V^B$ we have $||x\in Y||=||x\in X||\cdot ||\varphi(x)||$ and this gives (14.22).

I have a few questions about this proof:

1. How are we meant to parse $||(\forall z\in X)(\varphi(z)\leftrightarrow z\in Y)||$? Am I correct to interpret it as $\prod_{z\in \text{dom}(X)}||\varphi(z)\leftrightarrow z\in Y||$? **EDIT:** This is incorrect. It should be $\prod_{z\in \text{dom}(X)}(X(z)\Rightarrow||\varphi(z)\leftrightarrow z\in Y||).$
2. How do we arrive at $||x\in Y||=||x\in X||\cdot ||\varphi(x)||$? I was able to get as far as
   $$||x\in Y||=\sum_{t\in \text{dom}(Y)}(||x=t||\cdot Y(t))=\sum_{t\in \text{dom}(X)}(||x=t||\cdot X(t)\cdot ||\varphi(t)||),$$
   which *almost* looks like $||x\in X||\cdot ||\varphi(x)||$, but I don't understand how to relate $||\varphi(t)||$ to $||\varphi(x)||$.
3. Once we have this, how does (14.22) follow? I understand how
   $$||Y\subseteq X||=\prod_{t\in \text{dom}(Y)}(Y(t)\Rightarrow ||t\in X||)\geq \prod_{t\in \text{dom}(Y)}(Y(t)\Rightarrow ||t\in Y||)=1,$$
   where the last equality follows from $Y(t)\leq ||t\in Y||$, but I'm having more trouble with the second part. Using the corrected interpretation from my first question, it suffices to show that
   $$(X(z)\Rightarrow||\varphi(z)\leftrightarrow z\in Y||)=1$$
   for all $z\in \text{dom}(X)$. I believe this means I need
   $$(X(z)\Rightarrow(||\varphi(z)||\Rightarrow ||z\in Y||))=1 \text{ and }(X(z)\Rightarrow(||z\in Y||\Rightarrow||\varphi(z)||))=1.$$
   The latter follows easily from $||z\in Y||\leq \varphi(z)$, but I don't see how to get the former. Can I get some help?

Comment: I think you should have $\lVert x = t \rVert \cdot \lVert \varphi(t) \rVert = \lVert x = t \rVert \cdot \lVert \varphi(x) \rVert$.  Unless I'm misunderstanding the notation (which I'm not too familiar with).

Comment: The proposed "parsing" in your question 1 is incorrect. You might need to go back to the definitions of bounded quantifiers and of truth values of quantified statements. But if you're lucky Jech has an earlier lemma (or proposition) describing the truth values of formulas that begin with a bounded quantifier like $(\forall z\in X)$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Ah, I found the relevant lemma. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1): Typically, $(\forall x \in X) \phi(x)$ is taken to be purely syntactic sugar for the formula $(\forall x) (x \in X \rightarrow \varphi(x))$.  From here, you would use the usual rules to say
$$\lVert (\forall x) (x \in X \rightarrow \varphi(x)) \rVert = \prod_{x \in V^B} ( \lVert x \in X \rVert \Rightarrow \lVert \varphi(x) \rVert).$$
However, as Andreas Blass and you mention, there is a convenience lemma which states that this is equal to
$$\prod_{t \in \operatorname{dom}(X)} (X(t) \Rightarrow \lVert \varphi(x) \rVert)$$
and this is often easier to work with.

(2): For each $t\in \operatorname{dom}(X)$, we have $\lVert x=t \rVert \cdot \lVert \varphi(t) \rVert = \lVert x=t \rVert \cdot \lVert \varphi(x) \rVert$, from which you can proceed from your expression to:
$$\sum_{t \in \operatorname{dom}(X)} X(t) \cdot \lVert x=t \rVert \cdot \lVert \varphi(t) \rVert = \sum X(t) \cdot \lVert x=t \rVert \cdot \lVert \varphi(x) \rVert = \\ \left( \sum X(t) \cdot \lVert x=t \rVert \right) \cdot \lVert \varphi(x) \rVert = \lVert x \in X \rVert \cdot \lVert \varphi(x) \rVert.$$

To see that $\lVert x=t \rVert \cdot \lVert \varphi(t) \rVert = \lVert x=t \rVert \cdot \lVert \varphi(x) \rVert$, we use what should presumably have been a previous lemma.  Namely: suppose $\Gamma$ is a set of (context) formulas, and $\varphi$ a target formula.  Also, suppose that $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ in pure first-order logic.  Then for any assignment of free term variables of formulas in $\Gamma$ and free term variables in $\varphi$ to elements of $V^B$, and similarly for assignment of free propositional variables in $\Gamma$ and $\varphi$ to elements of $B$, we have $\prod_{\gamma \in \Gamma} \lVert \gamma \rVert \le \lVert \varphi \rVert$.  (We eventually want to apply this in the special case that $\Gamma$ is the set of axioms of ZFC; but it is useful in the interim also.)

Now, $\{ x=t, \varphi(t) \} \vdash (x=t) \land \varphi(x)$ is easy to see using the substitution principle; therefore, $\lVert x=t \rVert \cdot \lVert \varphi(t) \rVert \le \lVert x=t \rVert \cdot \lVert \varphi(x) \rVert$.  The converse inequality $\lVert x=t \rVert \cdot \lVert \varphi(x) \rVert \le \lVert x=t \rVert \cdot \lVert \varphi(t) \rVert$ is proved in a very similar way.

(3): Since $p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)$ is logically equivalent to $(p\land q) \rightarrow r$ in pure first-order logic, by applying the lemma mentioned in the previous part again, we see that
$$(X(z) \Rightarrow (\lVert \varphi(z) \rVert \Rightarrow \lVert z \in Y \rVert)) = ((X(z) \cdot \lVert \varphi(z) \rVert) \Rightarrow \lVert z \in Y \rVert).$$
Therefore, to show this is equal to 1, it is sufficient to show $X(z) \cdot \lVert \varphi(z) \rVert \le \lVert z \in Y \rVert$.  However, $X(z) \le \lVert z \in X \rVert$; therefore,
$$X(z) \cdot \lVert \varphi(z) \rVert \le \lVert z \in X \rVert \cdot \lVert \varphi(z) \rVert = \lVert z \in Y \rVert$$
as required.